# Bootstrap columns with flexbox are not taking proper width on iOS and Safari

Tags: ios, css, safari, flexbox

I am trying to use flex box with bootstrap columns so that all the columns are always horizontally centered. The markup mentioned below works fine for firefox, chrome and Android but fails on iOS and safari. I haven't tested IE yet.

**HTML:**

```
<!-- The fourth column falls down -->
<div class='row row-1 text-center'>
    <div class="col-xs-3 red">Hi</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 blue">Hi</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 blue">Hi</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 blue">Hi</div>
</div>
<!-- Works Fine and centers the columns -->  
<div class='row text-center'>
    <div class="col-xs-3 red">Hi</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 blue">Hi</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 blue">Hi</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex; 
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
            justify-content: center;
}
div[class^=col-] {
  float: none;  
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

On Chrome, Firefox and Android

[image]

On Safari and iOS

[image]

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kirandash/4cay7537/)**

Is there anything that I should be adding to the columns so that they appear in one line.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's `pseudo-element` in the `.row` causing the problem.

> This happens because Safari browser treats `:before` and `:after`
>   pseudo-elements as if they were real elements.

Try

```
 .row:before, .row:after{
      display: none;
    }
```

or better create a class say, `.flex-row` and do this

```
<div class="row flex-row">
  {{contents here..}}
</div>


.flex-row{
     display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex; 
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
            justify-content: center;
}
.flex-row:before, .flex-row:after{
   display: none;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4cay7537/12/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. That solved the issue. Have a great day

Comment: Welcome mate, I had this same issue when I started using flex. good day :)

Comment: Hi Jinu. Do you have any solution for centering the bootstrap columns without using flexbox? I am using Modernizr to detect if flexbox is not supported and floating the elements to left. But I would love to center it for non flexbox supported browsers too.

Comment: @KiranDash check out this awesome article https://scotch.io/bar-talk/different-tricks-on-how-to-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height

Comment: Thanks a lot for the URL.

Answer (score -2):

If anyone is still lost for a solution, I had an issue where my columns were TALL in Safari:

[image]

To solve this, I simply added this CSS selector (I know `!important` isn't best practice, but I tried several solutions and eventually landed on this):

```css
.d-flex {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Now, my columns looks like this, which is how it originally looked in Chrome, Firefox, etc.:

[image]

Comment: `display: block` makes the flex-element a block-element. So if you don't want to use flexboxes, just don't use them in the first place.